# Tap to action widget

Tags: android, widget, tap

I am trying to find a widget or library in Android that looks like a tapping finger that I can use to show a hint to the user that he can tap on a certain button or image. Can anyone tell me how would this widget be called and if there is a library for this?

Something like this (but more beautiful):
https://dab1nmslvvntp.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/1443706760touch.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I found a library that has a TapTargetView, and combined with a pointing hand icon, I can achieve my goal:

https://github.com/KeepSafe/TapTargetView